# How to include a cookie in the initial WebSocket client request using akka Client-Side WebSocket Support?

Tags: scala, api, websocket, akka

I'm using the akka Client-Side WebSocket package to consume, from my Scala application, a WebSocket endpoint that requires a cookie header in the initial client request.
Looking through the akka client API docs and Google'ing around hasn't got me too far. Any ideas on how one might go about doing this?